# IIS 10 isapi_redirect.dll causing 500 errors until application pool is recycled

Tags: iis, tomcat, rewrite, coldfusion

Windows 2016 server, IIS 10 and Adobe ColdFusion 2018 using Tomcat.  The server has about 8 sites on it and one site is getting intermittent 500 errors.  All other sites remain up and responsive.  Failed Request Tracing shows "Filter Error - Incorrect Function 0x1"

The site will come back up if you recycle the app pool for that site, or restart that site in IIS.  I have the app pool set to recycle every 10 minutes, but that doesn't seem to help in minimizing downtime.

I've seen some vague references to possibly being a URL rewrite setting something that Tomcat doesn't understand, but could never find anything concrete related to that.  If I go through our rewrite rules one by one, each one works fine individually.

At this point I'm not sure what to even do with it.  In March it was doing it frequently (once per day or more) and we recreated the site - new web root, new IIS config etc. same thing.  Finally I noticed that the server had a pending restart from updates and once we did that it was fine until about 2 weeks ago.  Other than standard code updates to the site, nothing has changed with the IIS or Tomcat configuration.

Here's the isapi_redirect_log of the most recent stopping of Tomcat.

```
[Sat Jul 02 13:44:40.070 2022] [7048:452] [info] jk_log_version::jk_connector_version.h (21): Connector Version: 314863
[Sat Jul 02 13:44:40.070 2022] [7048:452] [info] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3627): Starting Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46
[Sat Jul 02 13:44:40.096 2022] [7048:452] [info] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3865): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 initialized
[Sat Jul 02 13:44:40.096 2022] [7048:1836] [info] jk_connector_CF_func::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3125): CF heartbeat started
[Sat Jul 02 13:45:14.574 2022] [7060:4948] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 13:45:15.101 2022] [7060:4948] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
[Sat Jul 02 13:47:39.554 2022] [7056:6320] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 13:47:39.915 2022] [7056:6320] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
[Sat Jul 02 13:48:14.095 2022] [2268:4200] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 13:48:14.993 2022] [2268:4200] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
[Sat Jul 02 13:50:57.816 2022] [6480:5716] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 13:50:58.200 2022] [6480:5716] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
[Sat Jul 02 13:52:03.676 2022] [7916:6864] [info] jk_log_version::jk_connector_version.h (21): Connector Version: 314863
[Sat Jul 02 13:52:03.683 2022] [7916:6864] [info] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3627): Starting Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46
[Sat Jul 02 13:52:03.708 2022] [7916:6864] [info] init_jk::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3865): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 initialized
[Sat Jul 02 13:52:03.708 2022] [7916:4216] [info] jk_connector_CF_func::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3125): CF heartbeat started
[Sat Jul 02 13:52:03.717 2022] [7916:6864] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (2270): current reuse count is 1 of max reuse connection 250 and total endpoint count 5000
[Sat Jul 02 13:54:40.115 2022] [6040:6052] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 13:54:41.005 2022] [6040:6052] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
[Sat Jul 02 14:00:33.757 2022] [1536:8096] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2834): Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.46 stopping
[Sat Jul 02 14:00:34.151 2022] [1536:8096] [info] TerminateFilter::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2868): CF heartbeat stopped
```

Comment: You will have to chase Adobe support team for analysis and resolution. The support contract you have with Adobe should cover components revealed in the log file. Note that isapi_redirector is not supported by Microsoft.